# Ayuda con error java.io.StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, java-stream

Estoy escribiendo un programa, y escribo y leo objetos de un determinado fichero. Los objetos les escribe correctamente, pero en el momento de leerlos, me da un fallo del tipo `java.io.StreamCorruptedException`.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    entrada e = new entrada("Mario", 40, 123, 39.5, 25, 15, 2019, 5, 7);
    entrada e1 = new entrada("Lucia", 5, 90, 12.5, 50, 10, 2019, 5, 7);
    entrada e2 = new entrada("Mariano", 90, 160, 40.2, 40, 30, 2019, 5, 7);
    entrada e3 = new entrada("Mariano", 90, 160, 40.2, 40, 30, 2019, 5, 7);
    FileOutputStream fichero = null;
    fichero = new FileOutputStream("datos.txt");


    ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(fichero);
    writer.writeObject(e);
    writer.writeObject(e1);
    writer.writeObject(e2);
    writer.writeObject(e3);
    System.out.println("----------");


    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("datos.txt")) {
        entrada en;
        while (fis.available() > 0) {
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            en = (entrada) in.readObject();
            System.out.println(en.getNombre());
        }
    }

}
```

¿Alguien ve algún fallo?
Además, quisiera guardar dentro del mismo While, las entradas en un ArrayList para luego poder gestionar con el mismo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy asumiendo que después de escribir en el writer hacer un writer.flush() y un fichero.close(), para cerrar el archivo que generaste.

En el método que lees el archivo estás creando varios ObjectInputStream's y solo deberías abrir uno.

Sería algo así:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("datos.txt")) {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    entrada en;
    while (in.available()) {
        en = (entrada) in.readObject();
        System.out.println(en.getNombre());
    }
 }
```